# PHP Create C string

Tags: php, c, message-queue

I need to pass messages to my C program from PHP and I am doing this via message queues.

I have the message queues working and both sides can receive messages.

The problem is on the php side formatting the data. I am trying to send C style string, but php handles strings much differently. How would I convert the php string into a null temrinated C string?

Basically I need 'config1' to be the null terminated string.

```
msg_send($mq_id, $MSG_CHANGECONFIG, 'config1', true, false, $error);
```

It appears php stores strings like so: \"s:8:\\"config1\000\\"; where \ are just escapes.

Is there any way to do this, or a different way to parse this from the C side in order to convert it to a C string?

Comment: Please post your `msg_send` functions, otherwise it's just guessing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
$nullTerminatedString = sprintf("config1%c", 0);
// or directly using escape sequence
$nullTerminatedString = "config\0";
echo strlen(sprintf("config1%c", 0)); # returns 8, so it should work
```

Taken from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php)

> **serialize**
> The optional serialize controls how the message is sent.
> serialize defaults to TRUE which means that the message is serialized
> using the same mechanism as the session module before being sent to
> the queue. This allows complex arrays and objects to be sent to other
> PHP scripts, or if you are using the WDDX serializer, to any WDDX
> compatible client.

So your call should be:

```
msg_send($mq_id, $MSG_CHANGECONFIG, 'config1', **false**, false, $error);
```

Comment: Looking at the data in the C program, php adds some characters to the beginning and end of the data...\"s:8:\\\"config1\\000\\\";...Pretty freaking annoying..I don't want to parse that in C

Comment: @user: looks like a php serialized string

Comment: That is not chars from normal php string handling, that's the output from [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function.

Comment: As knittl says, it's serialised data, which you are asking the msg_send() function to do (4th param). Changing this to false should prevent this. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add a null byte to it, use an octal escape sequence (you need to use double quotes for that):

```
"config1\0"
```